# Как запретить переход с сайта на другой?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, .htaccess

Как можно запретить переход с моего сайта на другой в .htaccess ? Скажем в комментариях поставили ссылку на другой сайт. Я знаю об этой ссылки но убирать ее не надо, но переход по ней заблокировать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю только .htaccess решить эту задачу не реально, но можно внедрить во все страницы js. Код из примера можно переписать на чистом js если jquery на сайте не используется. Ну и пример для доработки, например target в ссылках тут не будет работать.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://google.com">внешняя ссылка</a>
<a href="https://stacksnippets.net/">внутренняя ссылка</a>  

<script>
   $('a').click(function () {
      var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
      if (!a.test(this.href)) {
       alert('Привет!');
       return false;
      }
      window.location.href=this.href;
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Так она все внешние блокирует без разбору ?

Comment: @Helpsetup, ну можно например сделать чтобы блокировала только в определенных элементах, например <div class="comments">, или регулярными выражениями разрешать/запрещать определенные сайты.

Comment: Хорошо и как скажем запретить ссылки именно все ссылки на Google ? Все без разбору ссылки с сайта на Google запретить ? <div class="comments">  тогда пишем в этой строчке так: $('comments').click(function ()  А если именно по ссылкам ggogle.com скажем ?

Comment: Если несколько ссылок скажем ggogle.com и gggogle.com ?

Comment: @Helpsetup,  примерно так var a = new RegExp('/(ggogle.com|gggogle.com)/');  if (a.test(this.href)) ... Тебе показан путь решения, для конкретного кода нужно конкретное ТЗ

Comment: И да, вот .htaccess он разруливает только на сервере - отдал в браузер пользователю активную ссылку и там уже работают только браузерные скрипты. Можно приплести в эту схему .htaccess разве что как связка с mod_rewrite - модификация контента в момент отдачи пользователю.

Comment: Полностью это так выглядеть будет ?  <script>
   $('a').click(function () {
      var a = new RegExp('/(ggogle.com|gggogle.com)/'); if (a.test(this.href)) {
       alert('Привет!');
       return false;
      }
      window.location.href=this.href;
   });
</script>

Comment: Забыли поставить ! знак иначе окно не открывается :)

Comment: @Helpsetup примерно так. Я тебе показал направление решения твоего вопроса (возможно и единственное) и если оно тебя в целом устраивает я бы загуглил по подобным вариантам, или тут отдельно спросил с тегом javascript/jquery. Мой код не оптимален, для себя я как минимум парсил бы только host из href и по нему делал регулярку + скорее бы вырезал/подменял href у черного списка чтобы не терять например target="blank" у остальных. Ну и если JQuery у тебя не используется лучше переписать на чистом JS

Comment: Ну и мое решение это все же "костыль", по уму такие вещи надо решать в серверных скриптах например при записи/извлечении из БД, или при генерации контента.

Comment: Все хорошо но если убрать знак ! вроде работает а если поставить то окно появляется в обоих случаях что когда по домену что не по домену.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Pensioner/hgvL5amj/2/ Вот без

Comment: В начальном варианте alert был для всех не соответствующих регулярному выражению, а в варианте без ! для всех соответствующих регулярному выражению. Восклицательный знак я не забыл, а убрал.

Comment: Как быть ? Со вторым вариантом он мне полностью подходит

Comment: @Helpsetup - советую сформулировать задачу, показать мой код и попросить общественность его улучшить/причесать. Ну или если пойдет "и так сойдет" втыкать мой код.